# Function returning certain integers

Tags: python, function, integer, division

I am trying to create a 'def' function. It will include 'maxInt', an integer, and 'twoInts', a tuple of two integers. I will then have to **create and return a list of all the ints in the range from 1 to maxInt (not including maxInt) that are divisible of both ints in twoInts. Ex: if maxInt = 100, and twoInts = (2, 5) the values returned will be every number divisible by 2 and 5 up to 100, so 10, 20, 30, 40..etc. This would ideally be done using a for loop inside of the def function** I have something similar to this but is obviously not working

```
def isDivisible(maxInt, twoInts):
output = []
for i in maxInt:
    if i%(twoInts)==0:
return output
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We can only help you with code that reflects your actual attempt, not "something similar to this". More importantly, though, you must **ask a question**. (By the way: it's just called a "function" - `def` is just the language syntax that you use to write it, it isn't any special kind of function.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing the appended part. Add an element into output `list`:

```py
def isDivisible(maxInt, twoInts):
    output = []
    for i in range(maxInt):
        if (i%(twoInts[0])==0) and (i%(twoInts[1]==0):
            output.append(i)
return output
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want divisibility by multiple numbers, use their least common multiple:

```
from math import lcm

def isDivisible(maxInt, twoInts):
    m = lcm(*twoInts)
    return list(range(m, maxInt, m))
```

Before Python 3.9:

```
from math import gcd

def isDivisible(maxInt, twoInts):
    a, b = twoInts
    lcm = a * b // gcd(a, b)
    return list(range(lcm, maxInt, lcm))
```

Fixing yours:

```
def isDivisible(maxInt, twoInts):
    output = []
    for i in range(1, maxInt):
        if all(i % oneInt == 0 for oneInt in twoInts):
            output.append(i)
    return output
```